# Relaciones entre tablas MySql - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un sistema de comiciones en el cual tengo tres tablas:

```
tabla 1 "administrador"
id
codeEmpresa
empresa

tabla 2 "cominicionista"
id
idEmpresa
nombre
categoria //la categoria puede ser A, B o C

tabla 3 "cliente"
id
nombre
categoriaCliente //la categoria puede ser A, B o C
```

Explicación: cada comicionista tiene un cliente o varios y cada cliente puede tener varios comicionistas ya que hay varias categorias. Lo que no sé es que como relacionarlos. Intento hacer que el comicionista vea los clientes de su categoria y que los clientes puedan ver sus comicionistar dependiendo la categoria y eso es lo que no sé como hacer.
La empresa puede ingresa los comicionistas que quiera y tambien puede ingresar los clientes.

En un principio, se me ocurrui poner en una array() todas las categorias y de alguna manera cuando hago un SELECT realcionarlos con el array, pero tampoco se como hacer eso.... je

espero me ayuden

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo es que hagas un modelo entidad relación, con tus entidades administrador comicionista y cliente. Al hacer el modelo veras que debes definir las relaciones entre las entidades y estas relaciones definiran las tablas que necesitaras en tu modelo físico. Por ejemplo si una empresa tiene muchos clientes y un cliente puede tener muchas empresas es una relación mucho a mucho y eso define otra tabla con los campos idEmpresa y clientes. Esta tabla se le conoce como tabla pivote y puedes tener datos extra por ejemplo tipo de membresia por ejemplo.

Comment: Entiendo.......